# Gerenciando multiplas subscrições no Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

Estou criando um tela que irá permitir que o usuário pesquise no sistema todos os registros de uma tabela de cadastro. Essa tabela pode conter mais de mil registros e estou colocando tudo isso numa lista que para o usuário é renderizado em uma tabela/grid. Algo nos moldes do print abaixo:
[image: exemplo de tabela]

Até ai a solução é bem simples, porem esta lista de tambem permite que o usuário mude os dados de qualquer coluna, então ele poderia muda as Datas da coluna "Date" para a data de hoje por exemplo. O usuário poderá ir de linha em linha editando OU tem um botão lateral em que ele digita o valor que ele quer alterar em TODAS as linhas e qual coluna vai ser alterada. E essas alterações todas são acumuladas na Tabela/Grid até ele confirmar que quer salvar todas essas alterações.

Nessa parte a solução já ficou um pouco mais complexa, mas não é algo impossivel. Porem até agora eu só estava dando o Contexto da funcionalidade.

O problema de fato está quando preciso enviar essas informações para o Back-end. Por uma decisão de produto definiram que não poderia mandar uma unica request com todas as alterações e jogar todo o processamento para o Back-end. Ficou decidido que quando o usuário confirmasse as alterações, o sistema iria enviar, para cada linha alterada, uma requisição para alteração e que o Front iria controlar isso.

O problema é que quando tinha 10~15 requests simultaneas para fazer o browser conseguia segurar a pancada e trabalhar todas elas e controlar todas elas. O verdadeiro erro acontece quando temos que enviar mais de 100 requisições simultaneas, nesse momento o browser chega até a congelar de tanta requisição que ele envia.

Para resolver isso eu criei uma lógica de controle que demonstro abaixo:

```
 async loopRequests(){
    let lsWaitingReqs: Array<ISubControl> = this.lsRequests.filter((x)=> x.status === StatusSubscription.WAITING)
    let lsRunningReqs: Array<ISubControl> = this.lsRequests.filter((x)=> x.status === StatusSubscription.STARTED)
    let lsDoneReqs: Array<ISubControl> = this.getFinishedRequests()
    let count: number = 0;
    this.loopExecuting = true

    // While my Done List has less itens then my requestList we must check if I can subscribe

    while(lsDoneReqs.length !== this.lsRequests.length){
        
        // While I have less running requests then max quantity, create another subscribe
        if (lsRunningReqs.length <= QUANTITY_OPEN_REQUESTS){
            if (lsWaitingReqs.length > 0){
                const nextReq: IAltLoteTipoSubControl = lsWaitingReqs[0]
                this.callProgressRefresh();

                this.updateItemReqStack(nextReq, StatusSubscription.STARTED);
                // The execRequest subscribes the request and when done it moves the StatusSubscription to Done
                this.lsSubscriptions.push(this.execRequest(nextReq));
            } else {
                await sleep(LOOP_INTERVAL_MS);  
            }
        } else {
            // If its at the maximum parallel requests, sleep to try again
            await sleep(LOOP_INTERVAL_MS);
        }
        
        // update the progressbar
        this.callProgressRefresh();

        // Update control lists
        lsRunningReqs = this.lsRequests.filter((x)=> x.status === StatusSubscription.STARTED);
        lsWaitingReqs = this.lsRequests.filter((x)=> x.status === StatusSubscription.WAITING);
        lsDoneReqs    = this.getFinishedRequests()
    }
    this.loopExecuting = false
}
```

Explicando ela um pouco, eu criei uma lista que guarda todas as requisições que serão executadas e nessa função eu executo uma quantidade X de requisições ( controlado pela const QUANTITY_OPEN_REQUESTS iniciada em 5 ). Enquanto eu puder abrir requisições eu vou gerando os subscribes e eles vão realizando o processo deles. Quando a requisição finaliza eu atualizo essa lista e marco a request como DONE.

Caso as 5 requests demorem a finalizar, eu não começo outra, eu rodo um sleep ( que é um timeout ) e verifico de novo.

Dessa forma o Browser não congela, eu consigo enviar todas as requisições e controlar todas elas. Porem na minha mente estou com um alerta amarelo para essa solução mas eu não achei nenhum artigo ou forum ou medium que me ajudasse a melhorar essa lógica.

Eu queria não precisar controlar manualmente todas as requisições, me sinto meio que reinventando a roda para ser honesto. Alem de não parecer muito performatico essa solução.

O que eu posso fazer para melhorar esse processamento todo?

Comment: Ajudaria fazer esse processamento em um [Web Worker](https://angular.io/guide/web-worker)? A ideia seria usar um thread em segundo plano para processar o lote de solicitações, liberando o thread principal.